"GLIBC_2.35 not found" after using "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" when installing pyopenvdb
I am trying to install a library called pyopenvdb on linux.
I was sucessful with using pip to install it but when I import it I get the following error:
ImportError: LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable not set. The pyopenvdb package currently only work on Linux x86_64 systems. Try running `find / | grep pyopenvdb.so` in a terminal. Find the parent directory of the pyopenvdb.so file and then run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[directory]` before running python.

I tried using the mentioned find / | grep pyopenvdb.so with no success, however I could find where the pyopenvdb.so file was located '/home/benceg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/' so I tried using the following comnmand:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/benceg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

After using this when I try to open python with python3.7 I get the following error
python3.7: /home/benceg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by python3.7)

Does anyone have experience installing the pyopenvdb library or with similar issues?
Link to the library page: https://pypi.org/project/pyopenvdb/0.1.4/#description
(I was also just a bit confused by the install steps so maybe I messed up some where, for example I skipped the docker installation part as I assume it's for windows only)
edit: bit better documentation from the github repo: https://github.com/theNewFlesh/pyopenvdb

Given their documentation, I think even on Linux you'll have an easier time using docker.
